# LaTeX listings Package Only gives Unbreaking Spaces when in tex4ht

Tags: listings, verbatim

I am trying to make a programming e-book, but the listings package is converting all of the spaces in the listings to non-breaking spaces.  I have tried `breakatwhitespace` as both true and false, as well as several other settings.  I have tried defining `\def\lst@outputspace{\char32}` and 
`\def\lst@visiblespace{\char32}` (as well defining them to be `HCode{ }` and `\`), though I am not sure I am doing that correctly.  In any case I can't seem to get it to stop outputting non-breaking spaces when run through tex4ht.

The way I know they are non-breaking spaces is that, (1) when I look at it in an e-book reader, they don't break if the book is too small, and (2) in the HTML code, it is peppered with x00A0 (I left off the HTML-y parts because I didn't know how to write those here).

Ideally, *leading* space would be non-breaking, but all other spaces would be normal spaces.

Also, if there is a different package I should be using, that is great.  I just need verbatim inputs from an external file.

I am using tex4book to build, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lst@outputspace` for configuring inter-word space, but id doesn't suffice to set it to normal space, we must also configure `CSS` for listing environment to break lines.

Try this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\lst@outputspace{\HCode{ }}
\makeatother
\Css{div.lstlisting{white-space:pre-wrap;}}
\EndPreamble
```

default `white-space` property for `lstlisting` environment is `nowrap`, which according to [Mozzila developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

> Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text
>   wrapping) within text.

This is clearly not something we want, `pre-wrap` seems better:

> Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are broken at newline
>   characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

Some sample - without linebreak:

[image]

and with linebreak:

[image]